# Error $mainframe->set() in joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla1.7

I have code in joomla 1.5

```
global $mainframe;
$html  = "web solution";
$mainframe->set('JComponentTitle', $html);
```

Use in joomla 1.5 is OK
But when using joomla 1.7 is error `Call to a member function set() on a non-object in ...`
I want help for this idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
global $app;
$html  = "web solution";
$app->set('JComponentTitle', $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the using of global objects in joomla 1.6+ is deprecated. Instead of using $mainframe and global $app, I'd use something like :

```
$app = & JFactory::getApplication();
$html = 'web solution';
$app->set('JComponentTitle', $html);
```